# How do I calculate an iterated integral?

Tags: integration

For $a>0$ exist $B\subset \mathbb R ^{2}$. Parallelogram with vertices $(0,0),(2a,0),(a,a)$ and $(3a,a)$. Write integral $\int_{B}^{} \! f(x,y) \, d(x,y)$ on two ways as iterated integral, integrated by x first and integrated by y first. Make sketch.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sketch below.

Let us integrate on $x $ first. What are the bounds of $x $? What are its value ranges? And depending on $x $, from where to where does $y $ vary? Notice that I included two vertical lines that should hint at different places where $y $ varies differently.

What if we vary $y $ first? For a given $y $, from where to where does $x $ go?

[image: paralelogram sketch]

**NOTICE** On the top right corner I have $(3a, 0) $ but meant $(3a, a) $.

I made another drawing breaking the parallelogram into the three pieces you have to integrate separately. For the triangles note that $y $ has a bound imposed by $x $. On the square, the bounds of $y $ do not depend on $x $.

[image: parallelogram separated in separate pieces]

Comment: x goes from 0 to 2a and from a to 3a,  y from 0 to a and from 0 to 3a